# Леовопрос/Лео-вопрос

Tags: орфография

Как правильно сделать это сущ., имеющее в виду 'вопрос Леопольда'?

`У меня для Вас есть новый леовопрос.`

`У меня для Вас есть новый Леовопрос.`

`У меня для Вас есть новый лео-вопрос.`

`У меня для Вас есть новый Лео-вопрос.`

Comment: лепрос-с - чего уж там, чего останавливаться в словотворчестве на полуслове

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:  ***Лео-вопрос.***

**Пояснение**

**Слитно** писать нельзя, такие слова контролируются словарем РАН.

**Раздельно** писать тоже нельзя, сравнить: гора Казбек, дерево береза.

Остается **дефисное** написание.

***Лео-вопрос***. А как это понять? Здесь нет притяжательного значения, иначе было бы так: ***вопросы от Лео.***

А как прочитать ***Лео-вопрос***? Здесь Лео – это приложение. Вопрос – определяемое существительное.